# Escape % (percent) in QSqlQuery::addBindValue() for LIKE

Tags: c++, sql, qt, sqlite, qsqlquery

I use an SQLite database with Qt. I bind the values to the query instead of passing them in the query string. However, I can't figure out how to properly escape a % (percent) in the bound value itself.

For example, how do I change this code so that it outputs `va%ue1`, but not `value1`?

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName(":memory:");
db.open();
QSqlQuery q(db);
q.exec("CREATE TABLE test (field1)");
q.exec("INSERT INTO test VALUES (\"value1\")");
q.exec("INSERT INTO test VALUES (\"va%ue1\")");
q.prepare("SELECT field1 FROM test WHERE field1 LIKE ?");
q.addBindValue("va%%%");
q.exec();
while (q.next()) {
    qDebug() << q.value(0);
}
```

Right now this outputs both:

```
QVariant(QString, "value1") 
QVariant(QString, "va%ue1")
```

I also tried with `q.addBindValue("va\\%%");`, but it didn't output anything at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LIKE pattern matching works on a different level than parameter binding.

To escape '%' or '_' characters, you must use the [ESCAPE clause](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like):

```c++
q.prepare("SELECT field1 FROM test WHERE field1 LIKE ? ESCAPE '@'");
q.addBindValue("va@%%");
```

Here's a function to escape any bound value:

```
QString sqlEscape(QString boundValue)
{
    boundValue.replace('@', "@@");
    boundValue.replace('_', "@_");
    boundValue.replace('%', "@%");
}
```